# What name shows in app store

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I am about to put my app on the app store. I want to customize the name that it shows.

I don't want it to show my name. How do I change the name displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the app name, it will display whatever you put in iTunes Connect. It doesn't use anything in code or the bundle to determine the name.

If you're talking about the seller name (since you say 'my name'), that's determined based on how you registered your developer account and is difficult (though not impossible) to change. If you want to change that, you need to contact Apple developer relations.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! So I would have to contact apple for this? I have yet to sign up for a developer account, is there a way while signing up for the apple developer account?

Comment: If you haven't created a developer account yet, you just need to do that and choose the name you want. It's only an issue if you want to change the name. Since you haven't picked one yet, you're good. I would recommend setting up a Business dev account vs a personal one. Same cost, but gives you a few extra features, like adding additional users which can be handy, especially testers etc.

Comment: Would this be the legal name that I have to set?

Comment: Yes, it should probably be your legal name, or at least a legal name. For example, my company's legal name is `Cerebral Gardens Inc`, but I have it listed as `Cerebral Gardens` on the App Store and I've registered a legal company subsidiary called `Cerebral Gardens` that's owned by the `Inc` company.